# My Heroku app is being used by another site

Tags: heroku

My Heroku-app is being used by other people, on other websites then mine.
Is there a way that only my site can use the app?
I have a small site so i use a free account, this way my free "dynos" are gone very quick.

Comment: Could you explain in what way these other sites are using yours?

Comment: by a javascript web application

Comment: That's not enough detail. Are they hotlinking your images? Making API calls to your API?

Comment: i use it for a CORS proxy problem in a javascript, now some others are doing the same using my app

Comment: In that case, you should restrict the CORS headers to your own domain(s).

Comment: can you please help me some further? i have no idea how i must do this in heroku

Answer (score 1):

You have some options...

1. If your app or api is being used by javascript web apps in the browser then setting a CORS heading specifying your top level domain should do the trick.
2. If your app or api is being consumed by other servers or non-browser based processes then specifying an authentication process such as http basic (user/password) should restrict access to the set of clients that you control. If your service is successful then congratulations! Maybe you should scale up and start charging?

Comment: How can this being done? I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your goal is to stay in the free tier at Heroku.

Heroku starts your dynos triggered by the request coming in on their router mesh. This means every authentication or blocking technique inside your application will still lead to the dynos being started (that includes CORS).

Heroku itself doesn't give you configuration for their routing in the free/low-price tiers. If you pay for it, there is [private spaces](https://www.heroku.com/private-spaces).

One possible solution is to have another layer over your app that does the authentication.

For example this could be:

- cloudflare
- Amazon CloudFront (not sure, with the Web Application Firewall)
- other CDN

These will likely have a free tier that's enough for you, but also be rather complex to setup for a beginner.

I hope I could help you a little